# Create list view of cases assigned to me or my team

Tags: list-view

I have a requirement to create a list view to view cases which are either assigned to me or my team (owner's line manager is me).

I do realise that owner's line manager is me can be easily filtered. However, it seems I can only filter the cases in my cases part.

I can think of a walkaround is to create a formula field to walk around this issue. But is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're assigned to those cases as a Case Team Member (there's a filter for that), you'd indeed need a formula field. It's up to you if you want to [Set Up Case Teams](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=caseteam_setup.htm&type=5) or not.